# Probability that the sum of the numbers shown is a multiple of $5$

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

> A regular die is rolled $n$ times such that $5|n$. Probability such that the sum of the numbers shown is a multiple of $5$ is given by $$\frac{a^n+b}{c\cdot d^n}.$$ Find $a,b,c$ and $d$.

What I thought is that we need to find coefficient of all those exponents of $x$ which are multiples of $5$ in the expansion of $(x+x^2+....+ x^6)^n$. Thereafter I am unable to solve it further.

Comment: It's not obvious (to me) how the fact that $5\,|\,n$ should play into it.  Maybe it's not a bad idea to ignore that restriction.  Working recursively, try to figure out the probability that the sum is $\equiv i\pmod 5$ for any $n$.  At a minimum, that should give you lots of examples to play with.

Comment: have you tried recursion? I.e. find a recursive formula for the probability of the sum being each of 0,1,2,3,4 mod 5 for each n a multiple of 5

Answer (score 2):

Using a little trickery with complex numbers, we can arrive at the sum of all coefficients of terms of degree a multiple of 5 of the above polynomial.

Consider the 5th roots of unity (i.e. the roots of $x^5=1$) and call them $(w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4,w_5)$

Observe:

1. If k is a multiple of 5, then $w_1^k+w_2^k+w_3^k+w_4^k+w_5^k = 5$ (obvious)
2. If k is not a multiple of 5, then $w_1^k+w_2^k+w_3^k+w_4^k+w_5^k = 0$ (not as immediately obvious, but not difficult to prove if you're familiar with De Moivre's Theorem or properties of Roots of Unity)

Let $P_n(x)=(x+x^2+....+ x^6)^n$ where n is a multiple of 5

Then we see that from our above observations:

Sum of coefficients of terms of degree a multiple of 5 $= \frac{P_n(w1)+P_n(w2)+P_n(w3)+P_n(w4)+P_n(w5)}{5}$

First, observe that when $w_i=1$ then $P_n(w_i)=6^n$

On the other hand, when $w_i$ is a nontrivial root of unity (i.e. not 1), then

$P_n(w_i)=(w_i+w_i^2+....+ w_i^6)^n$

$=(w_i(1+w_i+w_i^2+...+w_i^5))^n$

$=(w_i(1+w_i+...+w_i^4+1))^n$

$=(w_i(0+1))^n$

$=w_i^n$

$=1$ (since n is a multiple of 5)

Thus, $\frac{P_n(w1)+P_n(w2)+P_n(w3)+P_n(w4)+P_n(w5)}{5} =\frac{6^n+4}{5}$

Then the probability is:

$$\frac{6^n+4}{5*6^n}$$